# background image help, JPanel, JFrame, anything?

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jlabel

I want to make a background image for a game I'm designing but I cant figure out the right way to get the effect I want, I want a background that can be seen behind text etc. basically having the background cover the whole JFrame / JPanel not just one section of the layout (e.g. BorderLayout.Center) I think it does this anyway but if it does do that how do I make the background for those transparent to see the background which is behind...

Confusing i know but I hope someone here understands what I am trying to do and can help... this is my current code. I have been playing around with the background so dont read to much in how i have written it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

private JTextPane playertext;
private JTextField wealthstring, currentwealth;

public GamePanel() {

    super();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setBackground(Game.getBackgroundColor());
    Border raised = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
    Border lowered = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4), (BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raised, lowered))));
    add(northpanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(eastpanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);


}


private JLabel northpanel() {

    Font northfont = new Font("Engravers MT", Font.BOLD, 12);
    ImageIcon banner = new ImageIcon("images/banner.png", "North Background");

    playertext = new JTextPane();
    playertext.setFont(northfont);
    playertext.setEditable(false);
    playertext.setText("Player: \n" + Game.getName());
    playertext.setBackground(Game.getBackgroundColor());
    playertext.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

    wealthstring = new JTextField("Money: ");
    wealthstring.setFont(northfont);
    wealthstring.setEditable(false);
    wealthstring.setHorizontalAlignment(wealthstring.RIGHT);
    wealthstring.setBorder(null);
    wealthstring.setBackground(Game.getBackgroundColor());

    currentwealth = new JTextField();
    currentwealth.setFont(northfont);
    currentwealth.setEditable(false);
    currentwealth.setHorizontalAlignment(wealthstring.RIGHT);
    currentwealth.setBackground(Game.getBackgroundColor());
    currentwealth.setBorder(null);
    String wealthrounded = String.format("%.2f", Game.getMoney());
    currentwealth.setText(wealthrounded);

    JPanel wealthtext = new JPanel();
    wealthtext.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    wealthtext.setBackground(Game.getBackgroundColor());
    wealthtext.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
    wealthtext.add(wealthstring);
    wealthtext.add(currentwealth);

    JLabel northpanel = new JLabel();
    northpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    northpanel.setIcon(banner);
    northpanel.add(new JSeparator(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    northpanel.add(playertext, BorderLayout.WEST);
    northpanel.add(wealthtext, BorderLayout.EAST);
    return northpanel;
}

private JPanel eastpanel() {


    JButton tab1 = new JButton("Tab 1");
    JButton tab2 = new JButton("Tab 2");
    JButton tab3 = new JButton("Tab 3");

    JPanel easttabs = new JPanel();
    easttabs.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    easttabs.add(tab1);
    easttabs.add(tab2);
    easttabs.add(tab3);

    JPanel eastpanels = new JPanel();
    eastpanels.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    eastpanels.setBackground(Game.getBackgroundColor());
    eastpanels.add(easttabs, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    return eastpanels;
}

}
```

Comment: Did you try using a JLayeredPane ? You could also override the paintComponent method of a JPanel to display an image instead of the default background.

Comment: `JLabels` are components just like any other, so you could make one your content pane, and lay out other components there. The on top components may need to have their backgrounds transparent if that's what you want. (They *also* need to obey the opaqueness contract in that case).

Comment: I have not used JLayeredPane but would that not have the same problem?

and as i said before how would I set a background to transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you already have a JPanel that has your image as Background and you want to add another panel over it with your components you can use Opacity to achieve this. Only the components added to this panel will be visible. Here's the code :

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TransparentPane extends JPanel {

    public TransparentPane() {

        setOpaque(false);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


        super.paintComponent(g);


        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0f));

        g2d.setColor(getBackground());
        g2d.fill(getBounds());

        g2d.dispose();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! i knew there was a simple way to do it without having to create a new class and override super methods. To be honest I was looking in the java api for 'transparency' and 'alpha color' forgot all about the word opaque

Comment: Hope this helps,I should have just given you the setOpaque method but i thought you wanted some semi transparent thing which you can achieve with the class i gave you :)

Comment: either way helped a lot. I can use adjustable transparency for other things now i know how to :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends from JPanel and in its paint method draw an image over it.
Now create a class the extends from JFrame and in its constructor set its contentpane to the object of that JPanel class like below. Now you can add components to jframe.

```
class SimpleTest extends JFrame {

    JButton btn = new JButton("A Game");

    public SimpleTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(new CPane());
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
        getContentPane().add(btn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SimpleTest();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CPane extends JPanel {

    Image back;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        try {
            back = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("back.jpg"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        g.drawImage(back, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

If you want to make a jpanel transparent then do

```
panel.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: I tried that before but anything such as adding a JTextArea covers it up completely.

Comment: 1. change paint to paintComponent (in both cases), 2. missing ther initial sizing by pack(), otherwise there is only toolbar, 3. missing initial thread (more in Oracle tutorial), 4. (for potential upvotes to your answer) override getPreferredSize `inside CPane extends JPanel`, 5 g.drawImage(back, 0, 0, this);